# Multiple connection between android and php

Tags: php, android

I have a dynamic table in database and every time when there is a new insert I need to do some calculs and send the data to android , so I know how to do the connection between android and php but how can I make android do a multiple check to php file so it can show the data ?

```
 private void loadProducts() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        // converting the string to json array object
                        JSONArray products = new JSONArray(response);

                        // traversing through all the object
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {

                            // getting product object from json array
      JSONObject productObject = products.getJSONObject(i);
               int Temp_dt = productObject.getInt("Temp_dt");
                 int BusNumber = productObject.getInt("BusNumber");
                    Product product = new Product(Temp_dt, BusNumber);

                            // adding the product to product list
                            productList.add(product);
                        }

      adapter = new ProductsAdapter(WaitingActivity.this, productList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { Toast.makeText(WaitingActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

I expect to show the data when there is a new insert but it show just what exist in data table and if there is a new inser I need to entre again to the activity so it can show what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is basically a realtime update on android side (or client side) from MySQL.
I guess you have these options.

## Keep Checking for changes in every n Seconds

I think this is not a good solution. Because you are uselessly checking for datachanges and making network operations in a fixed interval.

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourtask,delay,interval)
```

## Use Push Notifications

This is better, as whenever there is some change in your data, send the push notification to client side to make the respective changes.

**You can check a complete Notification Tutorial from here:** **[Android NotificationTutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-G9283Ssd4&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hjM2NPKqtWQ_ndCuoqUj5Hh)**

## Use Firebase Realtime Database

The easiest solution is to use Firebase Realtime Database or FireStore Database. If you don't have any problem to migrate to a NoSQL database then this may be the best solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make server to send data without query from client. You have to check for changes on android in every N seconds. I think you dont want to send full table every time, so you can create field in database, that contains time of last update of table. It can chaged by trigger. When you download table first time, you save that time on android. Now you getting this time from server every N seconds and if it different from saved - reload table.

Or use sockets, but it does not supported in php, you need another server app

Comment: can I just update the Android Activity from a Background Thread? because i just need to do a multiple connection to URL_PRODUCTS and it will send the data which I need. Do you think this tutorial will help in this case ? http://cogitolearning.co.uk/2013/06/updating-an-android-activity-from-a-background-thread/